# Sort the contents of an extremely large (800GB) text file on Windows

Tags: windows, sorting

I have a *text* file with a word in each line, the size of the file is 800GB. I need to sort the words alphabetically.

I have tried using the *Windows* *sort* program using:

```
sort.exe input.txt /o output.txt
```

which gives the error: *Not enough main memory to complete the sort.*

I have 32GB of *RAM* so when I try specifying 10GB of memory for the sort using:

```
sort.exe input.txt /o output.txt /M 10000000
```

I get:

> Warning: the specifed memory size is being reduced to the available
>   paging memory.
>
> Input record exceeds maximum length.  Specify larger maximum.

What are my options?

Comment: Please do **not** crosspost. See [Is cross-posting a question on multiple Stack Exchange sites permitted if the question is on-topic for each site?](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/64069)

Comment: This is not a cross-post, I am not a machine so posting this and deleting the other takes a few minutes!

Comment: In the future allow the community to migrate your question

Comment: With Linux, you could apply this [method](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34092506/6419007). With files of 100Mb, it shouldn't be a big problem.

Comment: I wonder what happens afterwards? Will you load the result into Notepad or Wordpad? My point is that this large file will not be handled as "text" anyway, but being "text" (unstructured data) means you can only approximate operations for it, like seeking (I assume you are not going to read it through all the time). Depending on the actual usage you may better use some kind of database bred for a similar purpose.

Comment: This will eventually be loaded up into a file based DB such as _SQLite_ however the file contains a lot of duplicates therefore it is essential to cleanup and reduce the size first before storing them in the DB. It takes less time to do the clean up than to load it to the DB first then do the clean up.

Comment: What version of Windows are you using?  The sort.exe with the rather old Windows Server 2012 R2 claims to be able to do external merge sorting with the use of a temporary file on disk (without documenting a size limit).  Try using /T to specify a disk with 800Gb free for the temporary file.  And the message about "input record exceeds maximum length" seems unrelated to space - look at the /REC option and consider what your line terminator is.

Comment: I am trying this on a _Windows 10_ _DEV_ box. Very good point I think the "record exceeds max ..." error is due to some of the lines being very long, I should be able to exclude those and give it another try. Tnx for the tip.

Comment: I'm rather surprised that there doesn't seem to be any Windows external sort utility (that Google knows of).  But you might try building and running https://github.com/lemire/externalsortinginjava - the author Daniel Lemire is a well-known researcher in algorithms and the code probably works (and works well).

Comment: The algo to do the k-way merge external sorting is very simple to implement. My back up plan had I not received an answer to this post was to implement it in _C#_ but currently running _CMSort_ so will wait for the result of that, then give the _Windows sort_ another try and maybe at the end just for the fun of it I will implement it in _C#_ :-)

Comment: Yes, simple.  Simple enough for interview questions, occasionally.  Well, enjoy implementing it!  But you know, merge sort is just as susceptible to off-by-one errors as any other sorting algorithm ... so enjoy debugging it as well!  And then of course there's handling potential errors during I/O to the filesystem. I sort of suspect grabbing a jar off of maven will be faster ... though less educational ... Let us know the result!  I'll be interested in knowing about how to do this properly on Windows.

Comment: The pragmatic and fast solution was to use _CMSort_ which so far (after 30 min) has crunched through roughly 1 billion records (another 68 to go!) while at the same time removing the duplicates. The fun & curious part of me wants to implement it in _C#_ and no it's not going to be hard :-) Further more I never mentioned _merge sort_! I said `k-way merge external sort` which is completely different in fact it uses _Quick sort_ which I don't have to implement in _C#_ just grab a list and sort it. I will report back with the outcome when I get to do this.

Comment: "*some of the lines being very long*" are the lines long, or is it "*a word in each line*"?

Comment: @RonJohn: Given that the file is about twice the size of the RNC / Deep Root leak files, it's pretty much guaranteed that it's something like a database dump (and probably something quite similar, I don't even want to know what). There exist not enough words to fill a 800GB file, even with each word repeating about a million times (depending on language). That being said, assuming it was really "words" (with millions of duplicates, respectively), the best way to sort them would be counting, not k-way merge.

Comment: @Damon "*the best way to sort them would be counting*" does that mean to read through it, building a hash table of each unique token?

Comment: @RonJohn: Something like that, yes. Basically, you would want [counting sort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Counting_sort) only your keys are words, not integers. So you need a way to store the word-count tuple, for which a hash table or even something like `std::map` would do. Since the number of "words" is very limited (depending on language, but almost certainly less than 200,000) this is _very manageable_, and it's a single sequential pass over the huge file. Then you only need to iterate in-order (hash map is less suitable here, ordered map is better!) and insert `count` times each key.

Comment: @RonJohn: Consider that you will likely not have a SSD large enough to hold two copies of a file that size, let alone two copies plus the k partions. Thus, while your in-memory map has something like 15-20 GB/s throughput, you can expect a disk throughput of only about 100-120 MB/s, which dominates _everything_ runtime-wise. One pass versus 4 passes (read input, write partitions, read partitions, write output) will be 1/4 the effective run time, or less if you also consider seek times.

Comment: EmEditor can read your file by displaying and ranking all content every 248 GB https://www.emeditor.com/text-editor-features/large-file-support/ Maybe ask its creator if he can increase the size or if he has a script for that ?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

#### What are my options?

Try [Freeware Command Line Sort Utility CMSort](http://www.chmaas.handshake.de/delphi/freeware/cmsort/cmsort.htm).

It uses multiple temporary files and then merges them at the end.

> CMsort is reading records of an input file until the adjusted memory is reached. Then the records are sorted and written to a temporary file. This will be repeated until all records are processed. Finally, all temporary files are merged into the output file. If the available memory is sufficient, no temporary files are written and no merging is needed.

One user reports it sorted a file of 130,000,000 bytes.

If you want to tweak some code yourself, there is also [Sorting Huge Text Files - CodeProject](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/285123/Sorting-Huge-Text-Files) - "Algorithm of sorting lines in text files size of which exceeds available memory"

Comment: Wow, 130 megabytes!!! +1

Comment: @DavidPostill Are you sure that sort from [coreutils for windows](http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/coreutils.htm) is not more efficient (`--parallel` option if you have more than one core...)?

Answer (score 23):

One other option is to load the file into a Database. E.g. MySQL and MySQL Workbench.

Databases are perfect candidates for working with large files.

If your input file contains just words separated by a new line this shouldn't be too hard.

After you've installed the database and MySQL Workbench this is what you'd need to do.

First, create the schema (this assumes words won't be longer that 255 characters although you could alter this by increasing the argument value).

The first column "idwords" is a primary key.

```
CREATE SCHEMA `tmp` ;

CREATE TABLE `tmp`.`words` (
  `idwords` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `mywords` VARCHAR(255) NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`idwords`));
```

Secondly, import the data.
E.g. this will import all the words into the table; this step may take a while to complete. My advise would be to run a test with a smaller file first and once you are sure the format is the same as the larger one (truncate the table... i.e. clear it out and load the full data set).

```
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE "C:\\words.txt" INTO TABLE tmp.words
LINES TERMINATED BY '\r\n'
(mywords);
```

This link may help with getting the format right for the load.
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/load-data.html

E.g. if you needed to skip the first line you'd do the following.

```
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE "H:\\words.txt" INTO TABLE tmp.words
-- FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
LINES TERMINATED BY '\r\n'
IGNORE 1 LINES
(mywords);
```

Finally, save the sorted file. This may take a while also depending on your PC.

```
SELECT tmp.words.mywords
FROM tmp.words
order by tmp.words.mywords asc
INTO OUTFILE 'C:\\sorted_words.csv';
```

You can also search the data at will as you like.
E.g. this will give you the first 50 words in ascending order (starting from the zero position or first word).

```
SELECT tmp.words.mywords
FROM tmp.words
order by tmp.words.mywords asc
LIMIT 0, 50 ;
```

Comment: This **IS** the correct answer by a considerable margin.

Comment: This approach will definitely be more flexible, especially if you discover you need to re-run the sort with a different order, for example.

Comment: I don't care how fast your instance of _MySQL_, _MariaDB_ or any other _DBMS_ is, it is not going to come anywhere close to the the insert performance of _SQLite_ running on the same machine. Even with something as fast as _SQLite_ this amount of data is too much (and slow) to process (trust me I tried that first!) so the best solution is to sort and remove the duplicates first then insert to a _DB_ such as _SQLite_. So while this solution may be valid for some cases it certainly is not for what I am trying to do. Thank you for taking the time to post this anyway.

Comment: Ordering by `mywords` will take forever. Even with the `LIMIT`, it will take just as long as the whole thing because MySQL will have to go through every single value of `mywords` and order them. To fix this, you have to do the following after you've done `LOAD DATA`. Add an index to `mywords`. Now you can order by that column and not have it take a millennium. And it *is* better to add the index after loading the data rather than at the time you created the table (much faster data load).

Answer (score 7):

#### `sort`

There are many algorithms used to sort ordered and not ordered files <sup>[[1](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/3/why-is-quicksort-better-than-other-sorting-algorithms-in-practice)]</sup>.
Since all those algorithms are already implemented, pick a program already tested.

In *coreutils*  (from Linux but available for windows too <sup>[[2](http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/coreutils.htm)]</sup>), it exists the `sort` command capable to run in parallel under multi-core processors: usually it is enough.

If your file is **so huge** you can help the processing splitting (`split -l`), the file in some chunks, possibly using the parallel option (`--parallel`), and sorting the resulted *ordered-chunks* with the `-m` option (*merge sort*).
One of the many ways to do it is explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34092506/3569208) (split file, order single chunks, merge ordered chunks, delete temp files).

**Notes:**

- In windows 10 there exist the so called *Windows Subsystem for Linux* in which all the Linux example will seem more natural.
- Sorting with different algorithms has different execution times that scale as function of the number of data entries to be sorted (O(n<sup>m</sup>),  O(nlogn)...).
- The efficiency of the algorithm depends on the order that is already present in the original file.
  (For example a *bubble sort* is the most fast algorithm for an already ordered file -- exactly N --, but it is not efficient in other cases).

Answer (score 2):

To offer an alternative solution to Peter H, there is a program [q](http://harelba.github.io/q/) which allows SQL style commands against text files. 
The command below would do the same (run from command prompt in same directory as file), without needing to install SQL Workbench or creating tables.

```
q "select * from words.txt order by c1"
```

`c1` is shorthand for column 1.

You can exclude duplicate words with

```
q "select distinct c1 from words.txt order by c1"
```

and send the output to another file

```
q "select distinct c1 from words.txt order by c1" > sorted.txt
```

Comment: Any idea whether this will cope with an 800 gig file?

Comment: I'm not 100% sure - I tested the above with a 1200 line file (9KB). The developers page has a "limitations" page that doesn't mention anything about a maximum file size. A large file may still come up against a memory problem.

Comment: _q_ cannot process this amount of data remember that _q_ uses _SQLite_ behind the scene if I could not load the data direct to _SQLite_ what makes you think _q_ can?

Answer (score 2):

If the words on each line are from a limited vocabulary (like English) then you can sort the list in O(n + m log m) time using a TreeMap and recording counts (where m is the number of unique values).

Otherwise you can use the java library [big-sorter](https://github.com/davidmoten/big-sorter). It splits the input to sorted intermediate files and merges them efficiently (overall O(nlogn)). To sort your file looks like this:

```
Sorter.serializerTextUtf8()
      .input(inputFile)
      .output(outputFile)
      .loggerStdOut() // display some progress
      .sort();
```

I created a 1.7GB file (100m lines) with randomly generated 16 character words and sorted it as above in 142s and based on the O(n log n) computational complexity of the method I am using I estimate that 800GB of 16 character words would take about 24 hours to sort single-threaded on my i5 2.3GHz laptop with SSD.